# How do I get the Olympus OM-D E-M5's "multi function" button to be multi?

Tags: camera-controls, olympus, olympus-omd

The Olympus OM-D E-M5 has a `Multi Function` button, which the manual says:

> Allows rapid access to the selected function. Choose from [Highlight & Shadow Control], [WB], [Magnify], and [Image Aspect].

But when I press this, I just get the shadows and highlights curve control, and when I press again, that goes away. I've tried holding down and turning dials, but no. How do I select the "selected function"?

Comment: Do you have to add the additional functions to the MF button in some fashion, i.e. is there something under white balance which would let you do this?

Comment: If I do, I can't see where or how. There does not appear to be.

Comment: Out of curiosity, because this camera is on my "lust list", I downloaded the user guide. Page 93 seems to specify how you can map any single function to any of the function buttons. So is it the case that a function button can do any of these things but only one thing at a time.

Comment: @epo — you can map some selected functions to some of the buttons. Oddly, each button has its own restricted list of possibilities. _One_ of those options is, itself, "multi function", with the sub-list above. This is mentioned exactly two places in the manual: that page, and other page which points to the page on setting options, which then points back to page 93.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(To be 100% pedantic: The physical button is "Fn2". "Multifunction" is a software function that can be assigned to (some of the) physical buttons, and by default it's assigned to Fn2.)

Hold the button down and rotate a dial one step - either of the two dials, in either direction. Now you're selecting which of the 4 functions the button will be quick-accessing. Continue rotating the dial left or right, and when you've picked the function you want, release the button. From this point on, every press of the button activates that function. When you want to change it again, hold the button and rotate a dial anew. It may be a bit confusing at first, but IMHE it's easy to get used to, especially as your fingers gradually learn exactly how many dial steps there are between the functions.

At this point it would be hugely useful if you could also configure the exact list of functions you want covered by Multifunction - e.g. you might reasonably want quick access to ISO there instead of the aspect ratio - but this isn't possible; it's either that exact set of functions or nothing. If we're very lucky, some future firmware update might make that configurable too.